# What's the structure of the clause underlined red?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

[image]

The Prince. Niccolò Machiavelli. Harvey C. Mansfield. 2nd Edition. THE UNIVERSITY OF CHICAGO PRESS 1985

Comment: If you're reading this kind of dense and labyrinthine English text, you should have some idea what Machiavelli is saying?  Let's start with what you think it means.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the book is of challenges, and I have to refer to a(I guess I should use "a") Chinese translation from time to time. Figuring out the structure was more difficult than figuring out the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original sentence:

> From every side, therefore, **keeping guard in this way is as useless as keeping guard by means of colonies is useful**.

Let *A* be *keeping guard in this way* and let *B* be *keeping guard by means of colonies*. Then, now the part in bold would read:

> A is as useless as B is useful.

I hope that you can now better see what is going on here structurally: *A* is useless to the same degree that *B* is useful. The more useful B is, the more useless A is. *A* and *B*, kind of, parallel each other in terms of their uselessness and usefulness. That's what this sentence is basically saying.

Comment: Bingo. The key point I missed is that α's uselessness is AS SAME DEGREE AS β's usefulness. My exercise: Your answer is as clear as Machiavelli's "the Prince" is labyrinthine.

Comment: @Zhang Jian:  Bear in mind that Machiavelli did not write in English, but Italian, and that you're reading a translation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, it is a challenge, a great challenge. However, I should and will overcome it. So I sincerely need you native speakers' help. In fact, I'm reading TWO translations, the one is in English, the another is in Chinese. I'm doing my best to comprehend "The Prince".

Comment: I don't know why you've received downvotes and close-votes. Your question is perfectly legitimate.